# Configure xfce4-screenshooter settings

Tags: xfce, screenshot, xubuntu, system-settings

`xfce4-screenshooter` is the standard screenshot program in XFCE on Xubuntu.

How can I configure the settings about which format it saves the screenshot in and in which folder?

I noticed, that my settings I made in `shutter` also affect the settings of `xfce4-screenshooter` (but not all).

---

EDIT:
The man page sais, there is an -o option to open it with an external program.

How can I make this default? Then I could set there an external program, that automatically compresses the screenshot to an ***emailable* size**

Comment: Screenshots do not exceed 10 megabyte, so why wouldn't it be emailable?

Comment: I wrote *emailable* in italic, cause I meant, as small as possible ;)

Comment: You can always use this line instead to reduce the generated JPG's significantly by size: mogrify -resize 50% -format jpg *.png

Comment: you can also [replace the xfce4-screenshooter with `shutter`](http://askubuntu.com/q/297220) which has much more options, for example you can add an addon, that uses `optipng -o7 *.png` (see [how do I get maximal compressed screenshots?](http://askubuntu.com/q/298401))

Comment: I made my life easier and decided to use Flameshot instead. https://github.com/flameshot-org/flameshot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The man page of `xfce4-screenshooter` mentions some of its options, including this one:

- -s (--save): Directory where the screenshot will be saved

To save to a fixed screenshot directory, go to `Setting Manager -> Keyboard -> Application Shortcuts` and click `Add command`. Add this command:

`xfce4-screenshooter -s ~/screenshots`

Assign it to any key you like, like <kbd>PrtScr</kbd>.

PNG is the only output format possible for now, but you could write a script that converts the screenshots automatically to JPG every time you take a screenshot:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p ~/screenshots
xfce4-screenshooter -fs ~/screenshots
cd ~/screenshots
mogrify -format jpg *.png
```

Save the script as shoot.sh and assign a shortcut key (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScr</kbd> works fine). The command to enter is `sh shoot.sh`. If you don't need the PNG files and you only want JPG files, you can add

```
rm *.png
```

to the script.

E-mail integration with Thunderbird:

```
#!/bin/bash
SCREENSHOTS=~/screenshots
mkdir -p $SCREENSHOTS
cd $SCREENSHOTS

xfce4-screenshooter -fs $SCREENSHOTS
SCREENSHOTPNG=`find . -type f -mmin -1`
SCREENSHOTPNG=`basename $SCREENSHOTPNG`
mogrify -format jpg $SCREENSHOTPNG
#uncomment the line below (remove the #) for even smaller files (and comment the line above):
#mogrify -resize 50% -format jpg $SCREENSHOTPNG
rm $SCREENSHOTPNG

SCREENSHOTJPG=`find . -type f -mmin -1`
SCREENSHOTJPG=`basename $SCREENSHOTJPG`
thunderbird --compose "attachment=$SCREENSHOTS/$SCREENSHOTJPG"
```

Thunderbird supports more default fields, see [all parameters here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments_%28Thunderbird%29).

**Important**
Mogrify is part of ImageMagick, so you need to have ImageMagick installed. On Ubuntu, you can install it with `sudo apt-get install imagemagick`

Answer (score 2):

The suggestion from @Smile4ever to just pick a different folder is fine, but unfortunately `-s` stops it from then prompting you to run an application on the new image, and you [cannot combine this](https://github.com/xfce-mirror/xfce4-screenshooter/blob/fb5a29310af0ca96cf8f741e2b4dcf4f09c9309a/src/main.c#L194-L200) with `-o`. From [this](https://github.com/xfce-mirror/xfce4-screenshooter/blob/fb5a29310af0ca96cf8f741e2b4dcf4f09c9309a/lib/screenshooter-actions.c#L103-L106) I gleaned that [g-get-tmp-dir](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Miscellaneous-Utility-Functions.html#g-get-tmp-dir) was being used to pick a directory used with `-o`, so in order to keep the default behavior of prompting for an application *but* customize the directory, it seems you need to create a custom script like

```
#!/bin/bash
export TMPDIR=$HOME/Downloads
exec xfce4-screenshooter -f
```

in your `$PATH` and then use that script as the command bound to **Print**.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that

- the only format possible for `xfce4-screenshooter` currently is the
  Portable Network Graphics (PNG) format
- the location can be specified each time via the `Save As` screen

`man xfce4-screenshooter` is quite brief.

Answer (score 0):

Menu => Settings => Keyboard => Application shortcut => Add => type the command:

```
xfce4-screenshooter -r
```

=> press the keys you want to be the shortcut for this action (for me it Shift + PrintScreen) => done.

Answer (score 0):

## Xfce4-screenshooter

Open `Settings Manager -> Keyboard -> Application Shortcuts` to edit the default commands for the screenshot tool.

### Shortcuts

You can see my settings (on `Kali Linux 2021.3` in VirtualBox) in the following screenshot:

[image]

### Format

During the "Save screenshot as..." dialog, you can choose the format of the screenshot: `PNG`, `JPG`, or `BMP`:

[image]

If you need more information on the `xfce4-screenshooter` simply have a look at its man page:

```sh
man xfce4-screenshooter
# or via
xfce4-screenshooter --help
```