# How do I replace xfce4-screenshooter in Xubuntu?

Tags: xfce, screenshot, shutter

When I press <kbd>Prnt Scrn</kbd> in Xubuntu, `xfce4-screenshooter` starts.

I also installed `shutter` which has many more options to customize and to compress the screenshot into a smaller, better emailable size (see [how do I get maximal compressed screenshots?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/298401/how-do-i-get-maximal-compressed-screenshots))

Is it possible to modify the <kbd>Prnt Scrn</kbd> function so that `shutter` takes the screenshot instead of `xfce4-screenshooter`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change the shortcut in Keyboard settings.

Remove the `xfce4-screenshooter` ones and create your `shutter` ones.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also replace the default screenshoter `gnome-screenshot` in **Ubuntu 14.04 Unity** with `shutter` in the unity-control-center:

[image]

use `shutter -s` to select an area and `shutter -f` for a full screenshot