# Screenshot tool with integrated optipng or pngcrush

Tags: screenshot, compression, png

This is a followup question of

> [how do I get maximal compressed screenshots?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/298401/how-do-i-get-maximal-compressed-screenshots)

Is there a screenshot tool that has  `optipng` or `pngcrush` already included to minimize the filesizes of the png screenshots?

I personally favoritize `Shutter`, but any screenshoter would be great that would create optimized pngs.

maybe there are plugins available?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your favorite tool is **"shutter"** you can try to create a little plugin for it.

### Creating Plugin for Shutter.

**1)** Make sure you have installed optipng, or install it with:

- `sudo apt-get install optipng`

**2)** If shutter is running close it or kill it..

- `pkill shutter`

**3)** Create a folder for the plugin and give it the correct perms. *(eg:optipngplugin)*

- `sudo mkdir /usr/share/shutter/resources/system/plugins/shell/optipngplugin`
- `sudo chmod 755 /usr/share/shutter/resources/system/plugins/shell/optipngplugin`

**4)** Create the script *(eg:optipngplugin)*

- `gksudo gedit /usr/share/shutter/resources/system/plugins/shell/optipngplugin/optipngplugin`

**5)** Put this content in the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
TEXTDOMAIN=shutter-plugins
TEXTDOMAINDIR=$SHUTTER_INTL
PLUGIN_NAME=$"OptiPNG Plugin"
PLUGIN_SORT=$"Recompress"
PLUGIN_TIP=$"OptiPNG is a PNG optimizer that recompresses image files to a smaller size"
PLUGIN_EXT="image/png"
if [[ "${1}" = "name" ]];then
    echo "${PLUGIN_NAME}"
    exit 0
elif [[ "${1}" = "sort" ]];then
    echo "${PLUGIN_SORT}"
    exit 0
elif [[ "${1}" = "tip" ]];then
    echo "${PLUGIN_TIP}"
    exit 0
elif [[ "${1}" = "ext" ]];then
    echo "${PLUGIN_EXT}"
    exit 0
fi
FILE="${1}"
#LOGO="/usr/share/shutter/resources/system/plugins/shell/optipngplugin/optipngplugin.png"
optipng -o7 "${FILE}"
exit 0
```

In my case I choose the optimization level of OptiPNG to Maximun ***(-o7) (very slow)***, and I added an image as a logo.

[Man Pages](http://linux.die.net/man/1/optipng)

[image]

**NOTE:** *Feel free to change the script according to your needs*

**6)** Save the changes and give it perms.

> sudo chmod 755 /usr/share/shutter/resources/system/plugins/shell/optipngplugin/optipngplugin

**7)** In my case I edited a png logo with gimp, and I saved as *"optipngplugin.png"* in my desktop.

[image]

**8)** copy the logo to the plugin directory (give it the same name as the plugin plus `.png`) and the correct permissions:

> sudo cp /home/user/Desktop/optipngplugin.png
>   /usr/share/shutter/resources/system/plugins/shell/optipngplugin/optipngplugin.png
>
> sudo chmod 644
>   /usr/share/shutter/resources/system/plugins/shell/optipngplugin/optipngplugin.png

**9)** Test the plugin. Open shutter and take a screenshot of your desktop.

[image]

Right click in the screenshot and click in *"Run a Plugin..."*, then choose **"OptiPNG Plugin" from the list.**

[image]

**10)** Run the plugin to recompress the screenshot you took.

[image]

**NOTE:** If you have to add something to the script or some change. you can run shutter with this command to force it to reload all plugins

- `shutter --clear_cache`

Hope its help.

Comment: thanks, that works, although I get an error in the plugin selection: http://i.stack.imgur.com/qop8j.png.

Comment: It would be great to create an Ubuntu deb package from this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/332738/how-can-i-create-an-ubuntu-package-from-a-script

Comment: @rubo77... Great. glad it worked!

Comment: You can use another shell script plugin as template.  folder:
/usr/share/shutter/resources/system/plugins/shell/.
https://answers.launchpad.net/shutter/+question/118974

Comment: with "shutter --clear_cache" you reload all the plugins again.

Comment: the definition of `LOGO="/usr/share/shutter/resources/system/plugins/shell/optipngplugin/optipngplugin.png` is not needed if you name the logo like the plugin. Here is the finished script: http://pastebin.com/xEebiLhE

Comment: cool, with `shutter --clear_cache` it works. [discussion how we found out](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10160/discussion-between-rubo77-and-roman-raguet)