# How to set default save folder in Gimp

Tags: gimp

Every time I want to export a file, gimp opens `/tmp` folder but I want to change this to `~/Downloads` or any other folder.

How can I do this permanently?

**Update:**

Gimp seems to remember export folder for already exported files.

But when I use `xfce4-screenshooter` app to import the screenshot and then try to save it - the folder is set to `/tmp`.

Is there any way to point it to different folder in this case ?

I am not using any specific Desktop Environment - just `i3` with a bunch of additional apps.

Comment: /tmp would be a really odd choice - it is supposed to use one of the XDG_* folders. Do you have set up some of the XDG_* environment variables to /tmp?

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher You are right, gimp uses those Env variables. I have updated my question tho - my issue occurs only when I import image from `xfce4-screenshooter`.

Comment: A useful approach might be to tell xfce4-screenshooter where to store the screenshots and avoid or at least soften this issue - see https://askubuntu.com/questions/252738/configure-xfce4-screenshooter-settings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There does not appear to be a *direct method* to do this with Gimp but there is an acceptable *work-around* that may be enough for you. Use the following 3 steps:

**1. Export the Image.** First use the 'Export Image' as usual:

[image]

**2. Set your preferred location.** Next navigate to your preferred location and then use the '+' key at the bottom left of the screen to set this location permanently in the Gimp preferences. In my example here I am using `~/test`:

[image]

**3. Export your next image.** Next time you Export an image you will see your desired location in an easily accessible, single click location:

[image]

Not perhaps a perfect solution but this will hopefully fulfil your needs...

Comment: I am already using this solution but was wondering if there is a way to set the folder in gimp settings / configuration file maybe ?

Comment: I'd prefer it to default to "Recently Used" which already is part of the left bar, but clicking it each time is painful. In Gimp2.6 this worked as expected, but in Gimp2.10 it defaults to /home/$user/ which is useless.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that Gimp has no config for it an uses an operational system setting.

Take a look at [this reply](http://www.gimpusers.com/forums/gimp-user/19709-set-default-save-as-folder#message87009) for the same question:

> Priority of default paths for Export:
>   1. Last Export path;
>   2. Path of import source;
>   3. Path of XCF source;
>   4. Last path of any save to XCF;
>   5. Last Export path of any document;
>   6. **The default path (usually the OS 'Documents' path).**

I tested the Documents path (for KDE: System Settings > Applications > Locations) and it worked. My Gimp was using that setting.

I also tested changing the working directory, according [this reference](https://blog.bryanbibat.net/2012/02/21/changing-gimps-default-save-folder/) (for KDE: KDE Menu Editor > Advanced tab > Work path), but not changed the default save/export dir.

Answer (score 0):

I keep all versions of an image in the same folder. How can I make default save/export location the same as the folder containing the image I read before editing it? (Once I've saved the first image there, GIMP remembers that output folder.)

Answer (score -1):

I was able to change the default export folder. What I did, thanks to one of the responses above, was do a SAVE AS to the folder I wanted as a default, saving as an XCF file (very important to use the xcf file format). Then the next time I did an EXPORT AS the default folder was now the folder where I had saved the XCF file. And it worked quickly. The other method of making a remembered folder in the left hand column works, but for me it took a while to load the folder EACH TIME, thus not very user friendly. But, once you do a SAVE AS to the folder (make sure you're saving a .XCF file), your default folder for EXPORT AS is now changed. Kind of a getting around your a.. to get to your elbow situation, but hey, it worked!!! Yea!

Comment: This only works until you restart Gimp.  Export would have the same non-lasting impact.